# Display a confirm box on closing tab or window on chrome from a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I all,

Is it possible to display a confirm box on closing tab or window on chrome from a chrome extension.

I try Chrome.tabs.onRemoved, Chrome.tabs.onUpdated and beforeunload et unload and it doesn't work. In the better case it display a confirm box after the tab closed...

I would stop the closing process to allow the user to save changes not saved by the user before closing.

Thank's by advance !

Comment: Just to be sure, do you know about control-shift-t? (command-shift-t on a Mac).

Comment: @sowbug yes it open the last tab closed... but what's the link with my question ?